# Template argument deduction failure with Eigen

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

When I try to call the following function template

```
template< typename TDst, typename TSrc, int Rows >
TDst castFirst( Eigen::Vector< TSrc, Rows > const & pSrc )
{
  return static_cast< TDst >( pSrc( 0 ) );
}
```

by invoking

```
Eigen::Vector< double, 3 > pSrc;
auto const pDst{ castFirst< int >( pSrc ) };
```

I get a `could not deduce template argument` error. If I make `TDst` or `Rows` explicit, the code compiles just fine.

Comment: It seems to compile fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/EPKTYYK3b). Any other tidbits that could figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So it looks like it might be a MVSC issue.